# sanitize_option_{$option} filter returns null

Tags: theme-development, plugin-wpml

I have a problem that theme options is not updating, so after tracking down the problem i have reached to the `sanitize_option_{$option}` filter, so before applying the filter i `var_dump`ed the `$value` then `die` so i can see the result and the result was as expected (an array of newly updated options) but once the filter applies the result is null, i don't know why?

To be noted that i have WPML active, and also i have a custom plugin which implements the same options' class applied to the theme but strangely the plugin is updating but not the theme....

Comment: Have you tried deactivating theme & plugins one by one to find out if one of them is doing this?

Comment: actually, i have a pure WP installation without any active plugins but the WPML and the theme

Comment: Then deactivate WPML and check again, activate again then deativate the theme and check again.

Comment: It sounds like you have something on this filter that isn't passing the value through. Do you have any other code hooked to this filter?

Comment: @kero it is the plugin that making the problem but I don't know why

Comment: @Jacob Peattie it is my first time to se this hook